# Need to join two tables

Tags: magento2.3, database

Need to join two tables sales_order TO JOIN sales_order_item ON entity_id = order_id

Below is what is existing and would like to join sales_order to this.

Collection.php

```
<?php namespace Magecar\BackorderItems\Model\ResourceModel\Post; 

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection 
{ 
protected $_idFieldName = 'item_id'; 
protected $_eventPrefix = 'magecar_backorderitems_post_collection'; 
protected $_eventObject = 'post_collection'; 

/** 
* Define resource model 
* 
* @return void 
*/ 
protected function _construct() 
{ 
$this->_init('MageCar\BackorderItems\Model\Post', 'MageCar\BackorderItems\Model\ResourceModel\Post'); 
} }
```

Post.php

```
<?php namespace Magecar\BackorderItems\Model\ResourceModel; 
class Post extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb 
{ 
public function __construct( \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context ) 
{ 
parent::__construct($context); 
} 
protected function _construct() 
{ 
$this->_init('sales_order_item', 'item_id'); 
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check below code:-

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$connection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $conn = $connection->getConnection();
    $select = $conn->select()
        ->from(
            ['main_table' => 'sales_order'],
            [
                'main_table.customer_firstname',
                'sales_item.price',
                'sales_item.qty_ordered'
            ]
        )
        ->join(
            ['sales_item' => 'sales_order_item'],
            'main_table.entity_id = sales_item.order_id'
        )->order('fieldname','DESC');

$data = $conn->fetchAll($select);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data); die;
```

If you have any question let me know.

**`THANKS.`**